# SQL in my WCF Service Application

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, oledb, oledbcommand

```
"SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM Repair WHERE RepairDate BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'";
```

Hi all, besides changing it to parameterized queries, it there anything wrong with this sql? when i try to ExecuteScalar, it gives me Data type mismatch in criteria expression error:

```
public int TotalRepairCost(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
{
        int total;
        OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

        oleConn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM Repair WHERE RepairDate BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

        total = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        oleConn.Close();
        return total;
}
```

In my windows form button click

```
private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text);
        DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text);
        lblTotal.Text = client.TotalRepairCost(startdate, enddate).ToString();
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is there's something wrong with your date format.

Comment: @germi thanks germi, my data format for RepairDate column in my access database is Date/Time, and when i input my dates i inserted like this "10/10/2012" for startdate and "10/10/2013" for enddate, i also tried other options like "10/10/2012 10:00:00AM"

Comment: @yzwboy try using this query: `string sql = "SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM Repair WHERE RepairDate BETWEEN '" + startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' AND '" + enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use command parameters ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)) and `decimal` for `total` type.

```
public decimal TotalRepairCost(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
{
    decimal total;
    OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

    oleConn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM Repair WHERE RepairDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", OleDbType.Date);
    cmd.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = startdate;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", OleDbType.Date);
    cmd.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = enddate;

    total = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    oleConn.Close();
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) all fixed